# C++: Moving to unique_ptr

Tags: c++, unique-ptr

My problem is I'm frontend developer, but I need to add changes to C++ project.

So how it was:

```
std::vector<myObject*> myArray;
...
myArray.push_back(new myObject);
...
myArray.back();
```

How I try to change it:

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<myObject>> myArray;
...
myArray.push_back(std::unique_ptr<myObject> (new myObject));
...
myArray.back().get(); // this place looks not good in my opinion :)
```

A lot of functions should get `myObject*`. And I don't know how many changes will be if I change parameters of function.

Could you advise how to get the pointer correctly in this case?

Comment: What are you going to do with the last element in the vector? If you just want to call a function in it then you could do `myArray.back()->someFunctionInMyObject();`

Comment: Do you have a good reason to store pointers instead of objects?

Comment: @Scheff you cannot copy `std::unique_ptr`

Comment: @Scheff there will be no copying, and moving `std::unique_ptr` is very cheap. I think it is irrelevant in this case.

Comment: @walnut OK. I was not aware of this. I see there is a 2nd variant which I missed: [`std::vector::push_back(T &&value)`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/push_back). (It's quite new...) ;-)

Comment: @Scheff as I said you cannot copy `std::unique_ptr` so if `push_back()`  could not move it would not compile

Comment: @Slava I just realized that the `push_back()` wasn't the problem of the OP... (...and shouldn't have been).

Comment: @juanchopanza my manager's given me this issue. is that a good reason? :)

Comment: If you need to pass `myObject` pointer to functions without giving ownership then passing raw pointer is fine. Or you may consider to pass a reference instead. Should you store `std::unique_ptr` or object itself is another question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, you should use

```
myArray.push_back(std::make_unique<myObject>());
```

(or `emplace_back` instead of `push_back`) rather than `new`. Direct use of `new` should be avoided wherever possible.

---

You shouldn't have to call `.get()` on a `std::unqiue_ptr` that often.

You can obtain a reference to the stored object with `*`:

```
auto& reference_to_object = *myArray.back();
```

You can access members directly through `->`:

```
myArray.back()->some_function();
```

Only if you need a non-owning pointer (which should be much rarer than a reference) do you need to call `.get()`:

```
auto ptr_to_object = myArray.back().get();
```

or you can use

```
auto ptr_to_object = &*myArray.back();
```

for that (except in the very unlikely case that `operator&` is overloaded for `myObject`).

---

I think the issue is that as you say "*A lot of functions should get `myObject*`*". This should be much rarer than you make it sound. Only functions that would also accept a null pointer as argument should take pointers as parameter. Otherwise references should be preferred. The former doesn't happen as frequently.

---

Also note that you really should have a good reason to use (smart) pointers at all inside the `std::vector`. There are few reasons not to just use `std::vector<myObject>`, such as `myObject` not being movable, being very expensive to move, `myObject` being used polymorphically or references to the contained objects being required to not be invalidated when elements are added/removed. (Although `std::list` might work better in the latter case.) If none of these, or other reasons I forgot to mention, apply, just use `std::vector<myObject>`.

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot use make_unique. I am not brave enough to change C++11 to C++14. Sorry that forgot to mention.

Comment: Thank you so much for the full answer. So emplace_back is better? It will be like that - myArray.emplace_back(new myObject) ? Is it safety?

Comment: Whether you use `emplace_back` or `push_back` doesn't matter here. You shouldn't use `new` though. Use `myArray.emplace_back(std::make_unique<myObject>())` or `myArray.push_back(std::make_unique<myObject>())`. They do pretty much the exact same thing.